# Can the HTTP trigger in ELSA workflow send a response after completion?

Tags: elsa-workflows

I'd like to have the HTTP trigger of the ELSA workflow wait for the workflow completion and then send a response back to the source with an output. Right now, the behavior I see is only returning a 200 response as soon as the workflow starts execution.

Comment: Unless the workflow contains blocking activities that would put it into the "suspended" state, it already works like that.

For example, you could have: HTTP Endpoint -> perform some calculation -> doe something else -> Write HTTP Response.

Comment: @SipkeSchoorstra Thanks, will check. In the place where I've to use 'Delay', I've been using 'Timer' and that was the issue.